# custom crud.search() form in web2py?

Tags: web2py

I have a table definition which includes three fields & they are Home Phone, Work Phone, Cell Phone. I want to implement a one search text box using crud.search() to search among the three fields. for example I had the following table

```py
db.define_table('clients',
             Field('Name', 'string',unique=True),
             Field('Home_Phone', 'integer'),
             Field('Work_Phone', 'integer'),
             Field('Cell_Phone', 'integer'),
             format = '%(Name)s')
```

so I want to make crud.search() to show only 2 text box for search instead of 4. the first to be for Name & the second to be for phone number fields.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think `crud.search` can handle that (without some hacking in the controller to modify its standard output). You are probably better off using `SQLFORM.grid`, though even with that, you will still have to create a customized search widget to replace the default widget:

```
grid = SQLFORM.grid(db.clients, search_widget=my_search_widget, ...)
```

If you need more help, ask on the Google Group.

Comment: you're right, I came across a different idea which is to make a normal html form & make my own custom queries. thank you.